NSPageController to navigate in vertical direction
I am working MacOS application which has a menu on the left and panels on the right switches back and forth as we select a menu.
I would like to achieve the panel switching logic with NSPageController. By default, looks like NSPageController navigates in horizontal direction. Can we make this to navigate vertically?
If it was iOS app, looks like UIPageViewController does have an option to select NavigationOrientation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller
But I couldn't find any for NSPageController
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspagecontroller
And do we have any other option if NSPageController doesn't support vertical navigation?

A menu sits in the menu bar. Is "a menu on the left" a sidebar?

How about NSTabViewController?

@Willeke You are right. I was referring to a sidebar.

Looks like NSTabViewController is a good option. Thanks, Wileke. I will take a look.
